# Too many queries when preparing test data on salesforce

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I occured some 'Too many SOQL queries: 101' when deploying my apex code to production. After some investigation, I found that was caused by the queries in the Triggers of User object and Account object. When I prepare some test data and insert them into database, the triggers work and query for many times. A sample of my test code is like this(This is just a sample, actually there are more objects I need to prepare). Besides that, all the queries in my Trigger are not redundant, so I can't change my Trigger to reduce queries.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
    static void testMethod() {
        User user = testFixture.prepareUser();
        insert user;    //57 queries
        Account acc = testFixture.prepareAccount();
        insert acc;   //50 queries
   Test.startTest();
    //my test code
   Test.stopTest();
}
```

So my question is how can I avoid this error? I already searched a lot and I don't have any query in loop. Already tried to use the 'startTest' to reset the query counter, but it still not solve my problem. I wonder if there is a method I can disable the triggers when prepare data or any other way to solve my problem?

I tried my best to express my problem, if it is still not understandable, please tell me.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It feels like a bad idea to have triggers that call so many queries.  What do they all do?  Why do they do them?  Could those queries be done some otherway? <br\> Another option is to pre-load the test data you need into your Database.  That (SeeAllData=true) setting means that the tests have access to the complete database - not just the test data you have created.  Because of that, you could just create your user and account ahead of time and set up a query to pull those test records back.  The downside, you need to put that data into PROD as well.

Comment: @RobDavis Thanks for your reply . In my situation, there are really some program code there and I just want to use a minimum of time to make the test passed (it is blocking our deployment to prod). I'll try to create some test data in the database instead of prepare them. Thanks for your advice.